# Is there a way to build a graph that takes input from separate input pipelines for training and testing?

Tags: tensorflow

The [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data#multiple_input_pipelines) states that there are two ways of dealing with different input pipelines: Either implementing separate processes and graphs that load the model from a checkpoint file (e.g. `infer.py` and `train.py`) or by using a single graph and variable sharing. I am interested in the second case, but the documentation does not give an example how it can be done. It would work by constructing the model twice and accessing the same variables, but I am wondering how to do it using only a single graph. Perhaps one could pass a flag to a `tf.placeholder` that decides for one or the other input via a `tf.cond` node, or would that be inefficient because it would make the graph more dynamic between two `sess.run` calls, thus eliminating in-place guarantees?

Comment: you can use single model/graph & single pipeline too. Have a look at how this guy tried: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44321453/i-want-read-train-and-test-data-by-tf-cond

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow: run time test metrics and data queues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41360096/tensorflow-run-time-test-metrics-and-data-queues)